# boost asio tcp send and receive tutorial

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am looking for a good tutorial or example of using tcp boost asio to create a server that can send and receive string messages.

[This example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) seems to be a good place to start but there is no documentation, which is leaving me lost.

Any other better examples out there? Or could someone explain to me what is going on in the example?

Comment: Do you have any specific question about the example that needs explained?  The current question is not a good fit for Q&A.  Also, the Boost.Asio [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) may clear up some of the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

You should check this:

[The Boost C++ Libraries / Chapter 7: Asynchronous Input and Output](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html)